# Use Azure Pipeline to start Kestrel from command-line?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kestrel-http-server, azure-artifacts

We're currently using a pipeline to produce an artifact from a .NET Core project, and then deploying that artifact to a VM via a release pipeline. The pipeline grabs the artifact and unzips it to a folder on the VM. After that, we manually connect to the VM and start Kestrel, either by running the executable of the project or by running `dotnet ProjectName.dll`.

All of this works fine, except that we'd like to automate that last part. If possible I'd like to avoid having to reconfigure everything to use IIS. Is there a way to have the `dotnet` command executed from the pipeline, perhaps by somehow creating a service which can be started to execute the `dotnet` command?

For context - this is all for an internal QA environment. None of this will be exposed to the public, all traffic is firewall-restricted to internal IP addresses. The manual stop/start isn't really a huge problem, as we don't envision needing this for very long - just would be nice to have the whole thing fully automated.

Comment: Where is the VM located? Is it a VM stored in Azure?

Comment: Yep. The current setup uses an ExtractFiles@1 task and a CopyFiles@2 to unzip the artifact file and then copy the contents into a folder. Ideally, before running the extract/copy I'd stop the "service", and then after, I'd restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - so after doing some digging, I solved this by first using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to register a service which runs the project `.exe` file, and then adding two additional steps. Before the extract/copy, I added a script task with `net stop myService`, and after the extract/copy I added a script task with `net start myService`.